# How to pair items in array

Tags: php, arrays

How to pair items in array

`$array= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);`

i would like to display this array as

12

23

34

45

56

67

78

89

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Next time, please explain what you have tried and what errors you are running into. This is not a "script request" website.

Answer (score 2):

this code is what you are looking for:

```
$array= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    if (isset($array[$i+1])) // as mentioned in the comments, this will avoid the "PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 9"
        echo $array[$i].$array[$i+1] .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: it is not correct answer.you have extra 9 in the last line

Comment: You will get an `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 9` on the code

Answer (score 1):

Loop through a simple `foreach` , concatenate the first and next element using the keys and keys + 1 , and then push them to the array.

**FYI** : We know that there will be an undefined offset at `9` , thus adding a `@` before the array.

```
$array= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{
    @$new_arr[]=$array[$k].$array[$k+1];
}
array_pop($new_arr);
print_r($new_arr);

#If you want them as a string... uncomment the below line
//echo implode("<br>",$new_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 23
    [2] => 34
    [3] => 45
    [4] => 56
    [5] => 67
    [6] => 78
    [7] => 89
)
```

Comment: Think easy pal... The OP only wants to display the results like this - not to create another array.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple for loop.

```
$array= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
for($i=0;$i<(count($array)-1);$i++) {
    echo $array[$i].$array[$i+1].'  ';
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/133558)</kbd>

OUTPUT:

```
12
23
34
45
56
67
78
89
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
    <?php
    $array= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    $limit=count($array);
    for($i=0;$i<$limit-1;$i++)
    {

        $data[$i]=$array[$i].$array[$i+1];
    }
    print_r($data);
//output-Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 23 [2] => 34 [3] => 45 [4] => 56 [5] => 67 [6] => 78 [7] => 89 )
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way..**

```
$suppose= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

if(sizeof($suppose) > 0){

$assumed=array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($suppose);$i++){

        if($i+1 < count($suppose) ) {
        $assumed[]=$suppose[$i].$suppose[$i+1];
        }
    }

}else{

echo "No Items in array";

}

print"<pre>";
print_r($assumed);
```